# What is C# object pattern matching?

Tags: c#, casting, pattern-matching

I am aware of pattern matching in C# being something like:

```cs
if (x is TypeY y)
{
  // do thing...
}
```

Which is more or less equivalent to:

```cs
if (x is TypeY)
{
  var y = (TypeY)x;
  // do thing...
}
```

But, I found something while writing code that was suggested by IntelliSense.
I have the following code:

```cs
if (top is { } t)
{
  // do stuff if 'top' is NOT NULL
}
```

Originally, I thought I could do `if (top is not null t)`, which I could not; I then moved on to `if (top is int t)`, which is then when I had this suggested.
What does it mean? How does it work? I have only ever seen it in terms of pattern matching in switch statements, like:

```cs
class Point
{
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}

myPoint switch
{
  { X: var x, Y: var y } when x > y => ...,
  { X: var x, Y: var y } when x <= y => ...,
  ...
};
```

But, even this is fairly new, and I am not too familiar with the more advanced concepts. Does this relate to my question?

Comment: `top is { } t` is same as `top is object t` where `{ }` is anonymous `object` type. _Does this relate to my question?_ - yes while `{ X: var x, Y: var y }` is anonymous type with two properties `X` and `Y`.

Comment: It isn't the same. The first casts `t` as the same type as `top` (but non-nullable) whereas the second casts `t` as `object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is { }` is loosely equivalent to `is not null`, however, there are a couple differences:

1. It can be used with non-nullable types eg. `int`, whereas the `null` pattern cannot.
2. It can be used to cast the variable e.g. `top is { } t`.

When a cast is performed, the resulting variable is of the same type as the initial variable, but without nullability, so if it was used with `int?` the result would be `int`:

```
int? nullable = 1;
if (nullable is { } nonNullable)
{
    // nonNullable is int
}
```

The `{ }` pattern is most useful when used as a catch-all in a `switch` statement:

```
abstract class Car { }
class Audi : Car { }
class BMW : Car { }
// Other car types exist..

Car? car = //...
switch (car)
{
    case Audi audi: // Do something with an Audi
    case BMW bmw: // Do something with a BMW
    case { } otherCar: // Do something with a non-null Car
    default: // car is null
}
```